# MIT license with extra conditions

Tags: mit, license

I read many post and descriptions of MIT license and I have the question that If I use third party library with MIT license that the owner has add extra conditions that limit the use content and the must to share the license in all the apps that use in (it have to be shown in the UI? )

Is that legal or It exceeds MIT license that it said that you cannot limit the content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the MIT license has been modified, that is no longer the MIT license but some custom license. Using such a custom license may or may not be fine, although terms that limit its use might no longer be open source.

It is perfectly fine though to modify the MIT license. The MIT license text is not protected in any way. It is also possible to distribute MIT-licensed software under different terms, as long as that use still complies with the license.

Comment: That what I would know If he limit the access to the content of the code for example only can use 4 files of 50 that can't be under MIT lincense it will be another type but can't be MIT if the main rules are broken. I want to be sure about what I understand about your answer ^^

Comment: @solamente Such extra conditions do not break the MIT license. They are allowed. But that license is not the MIT license.

Comment: thanks for your replies now I understand clearly

Comment: If the license imposes other conditions, then yes it's not "The MIT License", but it also might not even be an Open Source license. Since MIT is not copyleft, that's of course permissible, but it's something you may want to watch out for.